# VBA - Change cell sign whether is values or formulas

Tags: excel, vba

I'm trying to create a simple macro to change the sign of the active cell or selection.
It works perfectly when the content of the cell is a value, but when it is a formula, it changes the sign but convert my formula to a value, like paste as values. I'd like to keep them as formulas if the content is a formula, any suggestions? Below is my code.

```
Option Explicit

Sub ChangeSignal()
Dim Cell As Range
For Each Cell In Selection
    Cell.Value = -Cell.Value
Next Cell
End Sub
```

Example:

If cell `C1 = A1*B1`, I would like it to become `C1 = -A1*B1` or equivalent.

If cell `C1 = A1/B1`, then `C1 = -A1/B1` or equivalent.

If cell `C1 = A1-B1`, then `C1 = -(A1-B1)` or equivalent.

Comment: I think I understood this correctly but still can you give couple of examples of what you actually want to achieve?

Comment: Sure. It is mainly to financial models and forecasts. Basically I have to calculate revenues, costs(-), expenses(-) and percentages (which are always positives due to the area convention) but for many historical and forecasting lines (more than 100). And I would like to to this vba code to automate a part of the process and make it faster, instead of the old F2, home, right arrow, insert or delete (-) sign.

Comment: Posted an answer. Hope that helps?

Answer (score 1):

Is this what you are trying?

```
Dim aCell As Range

'~~> Check if what the user selected is a valid range
If TypeName(Selection) <> "Range" Then
    MsgBox "Select a range first."
    Exit Sub
End If

For Each aCell In Selection
    Select Case Left(Trim(aCell.Formula), 1)
    Case "=" '<~~ Cell has formula
        '=A1 can be written as =-A1 or =-(A1)
        aCell.Formula = "=-(" & Mid(aCell.Formula, 2) & ")"
    Case Is <> "" '<~~ Cell has text
        aCell.Formula = "-" & aCell.Formula
    End Select
Next aCell
```

**In Action**

[image]

Comment: Hi Siddharth - is there a benefit to using `Select Case` + `Left` to determine if a cell has a formula instead of the intrinsic `.HasFormula` property?

Comment: So that I can tackle both text, blanks and formula in one go :)

Answer (score 0):

Maybe something like this? Just append `* -1` to the formula?

```
Option Explicit

Sub ChangeSignal()

    Dim Cell As Range
    For Each Cell In Selection
        If Cell.HasFormula = True Then
            If InStr(Cell.Formula, "*") = 0 Then
                If Cell.Value < 0 Then
                    Cell.Formula = Cell.Formula & "* 1"
                Else
                    Cell.Formula = Cell.Formula & "* -1"
                End If
            Else
                If Cell.Value < 0 Then
                    Cell.Formula = Left(Cell.Formula, Len(Cell.Formula) - 4) & "* 1"
                Else
                    Cell.Formula = Left(Cell.Formula, Len(Cell.Formula) - 3) & "* -1"
                End If
            End If
        Else
            Cell.Value = -Cell.Value
        End If
    Next Cell

End Sub
```

Comment: It's a possible way, solves the initial issue, but if I use it back and forth I may get some result like A1*B1*(-1)*(-1) instead of a clean A1*B1. Maybe I'll add an if ending condition as (-1) and then remove it from the formula if it is met.

Comment: @PedroCampos Ahh you want to be able to toggle it?

Comment: @PedroCampos See my new answer - maybe a bit complicated but it works!

Comment: Consider what this would do to a formula like say `=A1*B2`